# Unable to store user input in session storage using JavaScript Module

Tags: javascript, html, node-modules

I am trying to use JavaScript modules to retrieve user input (i.e., email address & password) from a registration form and set it to session storage.  I have tried several different approaches and still unable to store in session storage and not receiving any errors in dev tools in Chrome. Also, need to validate the email is correct in the registration script. Here is the project details to give an idea.

1. We need to allow our users to register for access to our application. To do so, we need to store our user information so it can be retrieved. Create a UserStore module that should store the users username and password in session storage.
2. The UserStore module should have the followings methods available:

   a. Get: Retrieves a user object given the email address.
   b. Save: Stores a user object in session storage
3. We also need a registration form for our users to sign up. So create a page
   registration.html and link to it from your home page. The submit for this page should validate that the user has entered a valid email address and if so should save the user information with the UserStore.
4. Finally modify, your login.js script to now retrieve the user object from the UserStore to use for logging in the user.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Tissue: Titan Issue Tracking</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta name="description" content="Issue Tracking System"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tissue.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userStore.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/registration.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
         <h2>TISSUE: Titan Issue Tracker</h2>
         <div class="topnav">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Login.html">Login</a>
         </div>
         <div id="loginwrap">
            <h1>Create New Account</h1>
         </div>
         <div id="signupForm">
            <form action="Issues.html" method="post" id="loginform" onsubmit="return handleReg()">
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="email">* E-mail:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail" required>
               </div>
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="Password">* Password:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Create Password" required>
               </div>
               <div class="labels">
                  <label for="password">* Confirm Password:</label>
               </div>
               <div class="rightTab">
                  <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" class="input-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
               </div>
               <div id="loginwrap">
                  <hr>
                  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
       </div>
         <div class="copyright">
         Copyright &copy; 2018 Titan Issue Tracker
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

UserStore Module

```
//UserStore: Allow users to register

(function (window) {
    "use strict"

    var App = window.App || {};

    function UserStore() {
        console.log("running the UserStore function");
    }

//Add: Saves email & password in session storage

    UserStore.prototype.save = function (userName, password) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
        sessionStorage.setItem("password", password);
    };

//Get: Retrieves username & password

    UserStore.prototype.get = function (password) {
        var userEml = sessionStorage.getItem("userName", userName);
        var userPwd = sessionStorage.getItem("password", password);
        return userEml;
        return userPwd;
    };


    App.UserStore = UserStore;
    window.App = App;
})(window);
```

Registration function

```
//User Registration


function handleReg () {
    'use strict';

    var userName = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

//Email Validation

    var App = window.App || {};
    var Validation = false;
    var Validation = {
        isValidEmail: function (email) {
            return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email);
        }
    };
    App.Validation = Validation;
    window.App = App;
}(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up revising the code and now it works.

UserStore

```
//UserStore: Allow users to register

(function (window) {
    "use strict"

    var App = window.App || {};

    function UserStore() {
        console.log("running the UserStore function");
        sessionStorage.setItem("admin@tissue.com", "admin123");
    }

//Add: Saves email & password in session storage

    UserStore.prototype.save = function (userName, password) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(userName, password);
    };

//Get: Retrieves username & password

    UserStore.prototype.get = function (userName) {
        var userPwd = sessionStorage.getItem(userName);
        return userPwd;
    };


    App.UserStore = UserStore;
    window.App = App;
})(window);
```

Registration function

```
//User Registration


function handleReg () {
    'use strict';

    var userName = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    var userStore = new App.UserStore();
    userStore.save(userName, password);

//Email Validation

    var Validation = false;
    var Validation = {
        isValidEmail: function (email) {
            return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email);
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("regForm").onsubmit = handleReg;
}
```